# Get Join Products and Customer

Tags: php, sql, performance

I would like join customers and products who have orders those products. Following is the database table structure involved in query.

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zenc_orders_products` (
  `orders_products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_model` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `products_quantity` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `products_prid` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `products_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_id`),
  KEY `idx_orders_id_prod_id_zen` (`orders_id`,`products_id`),
  KEY `idx_prod_id_orders_id_zen` (`products_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=384 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zenc_address_book` (
  `address_book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `entry_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `entry_zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`address_book_id`),
  KEY `idx_address_book_customers_id_zen` (`customers_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zenc_orders` (
  `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customers_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customers_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_company` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customers_street_address` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_suburb` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customers_city` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_state` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customers_country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_telephone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_email_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customers_address_format_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_purchased` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_status` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `orders_date_finished` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `paypal_ipn_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(96) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_id`),
  KEY `idx_status_orders_cust_zen` (`orders_status`,`orders_id`,`customers_id`),
  KEY `idx_date_purchased_zen` (`date_purchased`),
  KEY `idx_cust_id_orders_id_zen` (`customers_id`,`orders_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=337 ;
```

**Query:**

I have written the following query but **seems to wrong in join** as data is being duplicated.

```
SELECT distinct products_name, 
                a.customers_id, 
                entry_firstname, 
                entry_lastname 
FROM zenc_address_book a
    right join zenc_orders b on a.customers_id = b.customers_id
    inner join zenc_orders_products op on op.orders_id = b.orders_id
where orders_status = 1
```

Comment: Without knowing the configuration of your database it will be difficult for us to help you

Comment: I need to join table correctly

Comment: post your database structure

Comment: Perhaps post some sample data - the join look okay. But if a customer has more than one order for the same product, you'll get duplicates. Also, using "distinct" makes it really hard to figure out where you're duplicating things. I'd start by selecting "*", and seeing where you start to see duplication.

Comment: DISTINCT makes rows distinct. Do you really get two rows with exactly the same products_name, customers_id, entry_firstname, and entry_lastname? I doubt that.

Comment: I must admit that I always find right outer joins hard to read - probably almost everybody uses LEFT JOINs instead. So you want all products that where ordered with orders_status 1, even when all its ordering customers don't exist in zenc_address_book, right?

Comment: I need all customers who have orderd

Comment: If you are getting unique rows then there is no issue in JOIN.

Comment: OK thanks all of those who have participated in this thread. So its confirm that my query has no join issue?

Comment: That's hard to answer. The join is syntactically correct and so is distinct. As mentioned it is usually preferred to left-join, but a right join does the same job. The question actually is: does the query do what you want it to do? You say there are duplicates; we say there can be none. I say you get all products even when there is no related customer address stored; you say you want all customers who have ordered.

Comment: For a product ordered by customers A and B only, where customer A has no address in zenc_address_book and cutomer B has three adresses, you get four result records. So this works technically, but deems strange - what do all those addresses actually have to do with the product? I surmise you want another query altogether. I may be wrong, though.